# How to use the size of each node to find the number of nodes in given interval in O(h)

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

so given k_1 and k_2, find the range of a BST k_1 >= k <= k_2 in O(h)

I have tried a code with O(h + n) when h is the height and n is the number of node.

```
Algorithm countRange(Node root, int k1, int k2) 
{
   if(root = null) return 0;
   if(root.value >= k1 && root.value <= k2) 
      return 1 + countRange(root.left, k1, k2) + countRange(root.right,k1,k2);
   else if(root.value < low)
      return countRange(root.right, k1, k2);
   else
      return countRange(root.left, k1, k2);
```

**For example:**

`a[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` in array form

```
countRange(4,8) = 5; // 4,5,6,7,8
```

If there any way we can do it in O(h) times> The hint given in the homework is use the size of each node, which is the descendant node that each node has.

**for example**

```
     8    <- size is 7

  6     10 <- size is 3

4   7  9   18  <- size is 1
```

Comment: It's not possible to count the nodes without comparing their values so it would take `O(n)` time with the given constraints

Comment: Just think of bfs.

Answer (score 0):

One idea:

- assuming k1 < k2
- start walking the tree from the root. For some nodes (possibly zero) you will have both k1 < node.value and k2 < node.value, so you take the left path (or both k1 > node.value and k2 > node.value, taking the right path);
- note the first node where this is not true anymore, so the paths diverge. Let this node be D, then k1 < D.value and k2 > D.value (due to the assumption k1 < k2). So traverse from D to the left in search of k1 and count nodes with value >= k1; traverse from D to the right in search of k2 and count nodes with values <= k2. Add 1 (for D) to the total.
- when I say nodes with value >= k1 this doesn't mean only visited nodes. This is where having the descendant count for each node comes into play: every time you arrive at a node with value > k1, so you need to take a left to reach k1, also count all the right descendants of that node, since all of them will be > k1. Including the k1 node itself.
- on the k2 side the behavior is symmetrical: count all the left descendant nodes when you take a right, including k2.
- both these traversals are O(h), so the overall is also O(h).

> 

```
         20
        /  \
       10   21
      / \    \
     /   \    \
    2     17  22
   / \     \
  1   6     19             
 /   / \    /
0   4   7  18
   / \
  3   5
```

Let's search for [4, 18] in this tree.

- Start at 20, both keys are to the left so ignore this node.
- Arrive at 10 -- this is D where they diverge.
- Go left from 10 towards 4 counting >= 4, so 2 is not counted: 4 has 1 right descendant (5), 6 has 1 right descendant (7), total is 4.
- Go right from 10 to 18 counting <= 18, so 19 is not counted; 18 and 17 both have zero left-side descendants, so result is 2.
- In total you have 4 + 2 + 1 = 7: [4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 17, 18]

Comment: This is so complicated. Is there a algorithm I can follow?

Comment: Well, programming ain't easy.There may be an algo, but I don't know any, it's just my idea.

Comment: Also, you can ask on the Computer Science stack exchange site, you have better chances of getting your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Algorithm: countRange(K k1, K k2)
Input: Two keys, k1 and k2, that belong to nodes of a binary tree T
Output: The number of nodes with keys in [k1,k2]


1   Position p = T.root()
2   while(True)
3       if(k1 > p.getKey())
4           p = right(p)
5       else if (k2 < p.getKey())
6           p = left(p)
7   if (p.getKey() == k1)
8   int num = 1; Position small = left(p); Position big = right(p)
9   
10  //TreeSearchBiggerThan_k1
11  while(True)
12      if(small.getKey()==k1)
13          num = num + 1 + right(small).getNoOfDes() + 1
14          break
15      if(small.isExternal())
16          break
17      if(small.getKey() < k1)
18          small = right(small)
19      if(small.getKey() > k1)
20          num = num + 1 + right(small).getNoOfDes() + 1
21          small = left(small)
22          
23  //TreeSearchSmallerThan_k2
24  while(True)
25      if(big.getKey()==k2)
26          num = num + 1 + left(big).getNoOfDes() + 1
27          break
28      if(big.isExternal())
29          break
30      if(big.getKey() > k2)
31          big = left(big)
32      if(big.getKey() < k2)
33          num = num + 1 + left(big).getNoOfDes() + 1
34          big = right(big)
35  
36  return num
```

Thank you, memo, for your remarkable idea. I tried to make an algorithm out of it. Let me know if the algorithm I designed has errors. As a comment, getNoOfDes() does NOT concider a node a descendant of itself. Also, concider external nodes of the binary tree as dummy nodes, with null as both key and value.